# Should a Proof Summary be included in a Lineage Society application to explain minor conflicts?

Tags: proof, genealogical-societies

1. My parent's marriage license only states the county where they married. A wedding announcement in the local paper names the church, but gives the wrong (adjacent) city.
2. Birth certificates show my grandfather was 22 and my grandmother was 16 when they married. Marriage license lists both as 21, and no parents' names. Wedding announcement gives ages of 23 and 18, names grandpa's mother and gives address. Address listed matches the address on my mother's birth certificate 7 years later.

The bloodline through these recent generations is easily proven with other documents. Although not required, I'd like to include the wedding announcements in a lineage society application, for a more complete record. Should I add some sort of statement/summary explaining the conflicts, or let them speak for themselves?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have complete experience here, and I imagine many of the genealogical societies handle some of these things differently, but these are the two ways I would consider handling this:

1. **Include a proof statement/summary**. Including it probably isn't going to hurt your application, and may make it so the society doesn't have to come back to you to ask for an explanation.
2. **Ask them**. I started the process to apply to DAR, and every chapter has a genealogist who helps applicants determine their lineage and find the supporting documents. Whenever I had questions about my application, I would send off an email to the chapter genealogist and get clarification.

If the society you're applying to doesn't have a local chapter system with someone who can help you, I would recommend going the proof statement/summary route.